# db2 - How to get the min date and the next from the same table

Tags: db2

I have a table with date attribute and i need to do a query that gets the MIN date and the next of the MIN date

And I tried that :

```
select min(SC.TIMESTAMP) as minDate, result.TIMESTAMP
from Event SC 
INNER JOIN 
(SELECT TIMESTAMP from Event
 HAVING  TIMESTAMP > min(SC.TIMESTAMP) 
) as result  on  result.BUSINESSID1 = SC.BUSINESSID1
where SC.BUSINESSSTEP = 'CONTAINER_PLACING_EVENT'
and SC.LOCATIONCODE = '1';
```

Could you please advice how to do that ?

Thanks in Advance

Comment: Please define "next of the MIN date". Does that mean `MIN(SC.TIMESTAMP) + 1 DAY`? Or does it mean the next table date newer than `MIN(SC.TIMESTAMP)`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps you can rearrange your query into this form:

```
select
    min(TS), min(TS2)
from
    event,
    (select TS as TS2 from event where TS > (select min(TS) from event))
```

Add extra criteria as desired. I would try to rewrite yours, but it isn't entirely clear what the criteria for the count are supposed to be. If you are expecting more than one row (for example, the min and min2 of each `LOCATIONCODE`) then you will probably want a `GROUP BY` in there.

*Also, I wouldn't call a column `TIMESTAMP` as it is a reserved word.*

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `ROW_NUMBER()` [OLAP Function](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/db2luw/v9r7/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.db2.luw.sql.ref.doc/doc/r0023461.html):

```
SELECT *
FROM (
    SELECT 
         TIMESTAMP
        ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (
                 PARTITION BY BUSINESSSTEP, LOCATIONCODE
                 ORDER BY TIMESTAMP ASC
             ) AS RN
    FROM EVENT
    WHERE BUSINESSSTEP = 'CONTAINER_PLACING_EVENT'
      AND LOCATIONCODE = '1'
) A
WHERE RN < 3
```

This will return as rows instead of columns, but it should get you what you want. If you think your original query would have returned multiple rows (for multiple entities), you can change the `PARTITION BY` clause to include the column that makes them distinct.